# identifying descendants in action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, actionscript, event-handling

I am creating a sequencer in flash. I have 8 instances of a symbol track each with a play button. i want to use a single event listener to handle playing each sample on its own. the problem i am having is i cant give each button an unique instance name as it is inside the track movie clip.
here is my code:

```
masterContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
if(event.target.name == "masterPlay"){
    trace("master play was clicked");
}
if(event.target.name == "silglePlay1"){
    trace("track 1 play button");
}
if(event.target.name == "silglePlay2"){
    trace("track 2 play button");
}
}
```

all tracks are inside the master container plus master controls.
the single play buttons are in side the track symbols.
not sure if the code helps but is there a way of doing this without creating 8 seperate track symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumed `track1`, `track2`, ... , `track8` are the tracks you are having and the play button inside all the tracks is `playBtn`. Then you can create a singe listener for all also without having different names for play button in the tracks. (I added the listener for the `masterContainer` like you did)

```
masterContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
    var tapped = e.target;

    if(tapped.name == "masterPlay"){
        trace("master play was clicked");
    }

    if(tapped.name == "playBtn"){
        switch(tapped.parent.name){
            case "track1":
                trace("track 1 play button");
                break;
            case "track2":
                trace("track 2 play button");
                break;
            case "track3":
                trace("track 3 play button");
                break;
            case "track4":
                trace("track 4 play button");
                break;
            case "track5":
                trace("track 5 play button");
                break;
            case "track6":
                trace("track 6 play button");
                break;
            case "track7":
                trace("track 7 play button");
                break;
            case "track8":
                trace("track 8 play button");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I guess that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Handle click event in track movie clip, then in event handler dispatch your own custom event with bubbling which you can handle and compare event.target with your track instances names which can be unique. In other words your track component should be self-sufficient and encapsulate its own logic, which is play button click handling in this case.

Comment: in not sure i understand what your saying. i have been forbidden from putting code inside a movieclip (by lecturer)if that is what u are suggesting